# Displaying value of a double variable without Scientific Notation

Tags: android, double, scientific-notation

I have two variables with datatype double, when i multiply those variables they return result in scientific form but my requirement is to display result in normal human readable form. 
For Example:
when i multiply 9854795 and 8.9 it returns result as 8.77076755E7 instead of 87707675.5

here is my function for calculating values:

```
private void calculatingTotalPaymentAmount() {

    if (editTextBookingQuantity.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        editTextBookingQuantity.setError("Enter Booking Quantity to calculate Total Payment Amount");
        return;
    } else if (editTextRatePerBrick.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        editTextRatePerBrick.setError("Enter Rate Per Brick to calculate Total Payment Amount");
        return;
    } else {

        //MathContext mc = new MathContext(4); // 4 precision
        final double catchBookingQtyDoubleForm = Double.parseDouble(editTextBookingQuantity.getText().toString());
        final double catchRatePerBrickDoubleForm = Double.parseDouble(editTextRatePerBrick.getText().toString().trim());
        final double totalPaymentAmount = (catchBookingQtyDoubleForm * catchRatePerBrickDoubleForm);
        //bg3 = bg1.multiply(bg2, mc);
        //BigDecimal newValue = totalPaymentAmount.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN);
        editTextTotalPaymentAmount.setText(""+totalPaymentAmount);


    }
}
```

Comment: double totalPaymentAmount change it to BigDecimal and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Log.d("tag", "" + new BigDecimal(catchBookingQtyDoubleForm * catchRatePerBrickDoubleForm));
```